# Neo4j MySql Benchmark

Tags: mysql, neo4j

I tested out the performance of both neo4j and mysql on a simple crud process, I still wonder why does it take longer time on neo4j than it is on mysql. on select process i also experience the same result, where neo4j takes quite longer time than mysql. i wonder if im not doing things properly.

-----Neo4j-----

```
profile match (n:User{name:"kenlz"}) set n.updated = "2016-04-18 10:00:00" using index n:User(name)
```

Total update time for spesific user (3 records found) :  3139  milliseconds

```
profile match (n:User{enabled:1}) set n.updated = "2016-04-18 10:00:00" using index n:User(name)
```

Total update time for any users limit 1116961         :  27563 milliseconds

-----MySql-----

```
update tbl_usr set updated = now() where name = 'kenlz';
```

Total update time for spesific user (3 records found) : 1170  milliseconds

```
update tbl_usr set updated = now() where enabled = 1;
```

Total update time for any users limit 1116961         : 5579  milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Your operations look reasonable.

But please consider that the power of a graph database like neo4j increases with the locality of data. I.e. so-called [graph-traversals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal) (E.g. visit consecutive edges and nodes on a path), which perform really bad within a relational dbms like mysql.